# VisualSVN and VS2008 integration - moving files

Tags: .net, visual-studio, svn, visualsvn

If I drag and drop tracked .cs files to new folders in VS2008 with VisualSVN what message should I see when I commit the .cs file? I see added (+) shouldn't I see a "move"?

I'm asking because I'm getting ready to do a major refactoring (including moving lots of files) and I don't want to lose my version history on these files.

Note: I'm very new to Subversion, TortoiseSVN, and VisualSVN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added (+) is an 'add with history', also known as a 'copy'.

Subversion currently records moves as a copy to a new location and a delete on the old location. So: yes, this is expected.

(But the behavior might change in future Subversion releases as recording moves is on the TODO list)

BTW: AnkhSVN uses the name 'Copy' for this add with history, as that naming is more logical for users of other Visual Studio SCC integrations.